# Why I can't find tree view in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I am reading [Data Pipelines with Apache Airflow book](https://www.manning.com/books/data-pipelines-with-apache-airflow) In the book the picture shows a tree view however my Airflow installation doesn't contain tree view, is it removed in late versions?

My current version is: 2.3.3
The code of the DAG is [here](https://github.com/BasPH/data-pipelines-with-apache-airflow/blob/master/chapter02/dags/listing_2_10.py).

[image]

As you can see there is no tree view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Becuase in Airlfow 2.3, the Tree View was replaced with Grid View. Tree View was defunct and confusing.

Comment: I can see why it can be confusing at times but the tree view gives both multiple run times (unlike graph) and shows task dependencies. We're migrating now to the newer airflow and I miss that view. Is there a plugin or a configuration I could use to get best of both worlds?

Answer (score 1):

Apache airflow community defunct the tree view for some reasons from the version of Airflow 2.3. Instead of tree view grid view is getting introduced into the apache airflow.